# Make specific objects not identifiable in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, identify

Some objects of my layer have empty attribute table. Is it possible to make them unidentifiable - like eg. all objects of layer marked as unidentifiable in QGis project settings?

EDIT: Maybe I haven't described it properly, but I want to make unidentifiable only SOME elements of layer, not ALL

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's not explained in great detail in the [docs](https://qfield.org/docs/user-guide/index.html) but here's what it says:

> Often it is not required to be able to query every layer. Some layers are only present as basemap and their attributes are not of interest.
>
> You can manage this layerlist in QGIS desktop in Project ‣ Project Properties ‣ Identify Layers and uncheck the base layers.

I think in later versions it's under Project Properties > Data Sources. See screenshot below from 3.12.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I haven't described it properly, but I want to make unidentifiable only SOME elements of layer, not ALL

Comment: That isn't possible with just one layer, but if the elements you want identifiable can be determined by a condition (e.g. `"identify" = 'Y'` or `"field" = NULL`), what you could do is duplicate your layer (same file, just two layer references), and filter them using that condition. Then set one of those layers to be not identifiable.